# Virtualbox complains that I don't have headers

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, virtualbox

I've installed Virtualbox  (on Debian testing amd64)according to the [wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/VirtualBox#Debian_.22Jessie.22_.28testing.29). But I get this error:

```
$ virtualbox 
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
         Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
         headers, most likely linux-headers-amd64.

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

My kernel is 3.2.0-4-amd64 but the headers installed by `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,')` command is linux-headers-3.12-1-amd64 (There is no linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64 on repository anyway). Could the problem be this?

Comment: Why do you have kernel 3.2 with Debian testing?

Comment: What's the output of `grep 'deb http://http.debian.net/debian/' /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: @enedil what should be the current kernel version for jessie?

Comment: that `grep` query returns nothing (this is my [sources.list](http://paste.debian.net/83509/))

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/linux-image-amd64 It's 3.12

Comment: I honestly have no idea and I'm pretty sure I run testing: http://paste.debian.net/83510/

Comment: apt-cache policy linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64` gives me only wheezy sources. Either update your kernel, or add back your wheezy sources, run `apt-get update` and try again.

Comment: Run `# apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apt-cache policy linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64`
```

gives me

```
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64:
  Installed: 3.2.54-2
  Candidate: 3.2.54-2
  Version table:
 *** 3.2.54-2 0
        500 http://debian.lcs.mit.edu/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.2.46-1+deb7u1 0
        500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
```

So kernel packages for your kernel version are only available in wheezy.
Either upgrade your kernel, or add back your wheezy sources, run `apt-get update` and try again. For future reference, install `linux-image-amd64` next time. This will automatically pull in the current kernel for your version on upgrade. Of course, if you upgrade your kernel, you should reboot.

If you want to upgrade your kernel right now, a good way is to run

```
apt-get install linux-image-amd64
```

Whether you should actually upgrade your kernel right now, I'm not sure. Since jessie is currently a moving target, there may be further changes before it is a stable release. On the other hand, running the default supported kernel is a good idea. I guess it depends what your needs are. If the 3.2 kernel is working for you and has all the features you need, you don't need to upgrade. Since wheezy is stable, security upgrades for wheezy should be available for a while, even after jessie releases, so you should be Ok on that score if you stay with your current kernel for the time being.